# Using shelve to store the persistent data and have some trouble while retrieving it back

Tags: python-2.7, shelve

I am kind of new to python and I am doing a project in which I need to maintain the index of found records (like caching). Now I found that I can do this using shelve.

What I am doing is when user requests some thing try to first search in shelve index if hit return from there itself else go to normal algorithm and when found just update it in shelve.

I am able to achieve this functionality perfectly but the problem is I even need to maintain the order of the data that I indexed in shelve.

I found that when I fetch some records from shelve index they come in different order each time I make same request.

My mapping in shelve is many to 1.

for example:

```
myIndex['a']="abc"
myIndex['b']="abc"
myIndex['c']="pqr"
myIndex['d']="abc"
```

Now while fetching I want all keys (i.e. a,b,d) which have value "abc" in the same order as I stored them, that is `a` then `b` then `d`, but I get then in a different order each time.

[link for code referrence](http://pastebin.com/SQN2ZjDN)

Comment: How are you "fetching" the keys?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `myIndex` is a dictionary, and the enumeration order of a dictionary is not defined. You can solve the problem by making `myIndex` an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
import collections

myIndex = {}
myIndex['a'] = 'a'
myIndex['b'] = 'b'
myIndex['c'] = 'c'

for value in myIndex:
    print value # could print in any order

myIndex = collections.OrderedDict()
myIndex['a'] = 'a'
myIndex['b'] = 'b'
myIndex['c'] = 'c'

for value in myIndex:
    print value # always printed in the order you added the values, ie. 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

Comment: does OrderDict work with a shelve object...as myIndex here is not just a regular Dictionary but a shelve object which is similar to dict.